# Qt: Creating QStackedLayout

Tags: c++, qt, variables, header

Please take a look at the following code:

```
QStackedLayout stackLayout(this);
QStackedLayout stackLayout = QStackedLayout(this);
```

I have two questions: 
Why is the second statement not possible?
How can I call the constructor of QStackedLayout when I declare the variable in a header file not as a pointer?

Comment: I don't really understand your second question. Could you show some example code that you'd like to work and doesn't? Please also state the exact compiler errors you're getting.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I think you are misinterpreting the constructor. Qt takes a parent for its elements because it will manage their storage duration when created on the heap:

```
// here you need this constructor, so Qt will free the resource for you
QStackedLayout * layout = new QStackedLayout(this);
// here you don't need it, the object has automatic storage duration
QStackedLayout layout;
```

Then, if you want to call a certain constructor for an object declared in your header file, use the initialization list:

```
struct foo
{
    foo()
        : s("demo")
    {}
    std::string s;
};
```

The object derives from `QObject`  and thus is not copyable - that's why your second statement does not work.

Answer (score 1):

you should define stackLayout as a pointer

```
QStackedLayout* stackLayout = new QStackedLayout(this);
```

Answer (score -2):

The first question is easy: QStackedayout inherites QObject. You can never copy or assign QObjects.

The second question what you do is to call the constructor of QStackedLayout. But I suppose you really want to know, how to do this in your .h file? There only the default constructor is possible. Pointers are fine in this case. Or you put `QStackedLayout layout` in your .h file and add something like layout.setParent(this) in your constructor. I never did this. It looks strange to me. So I don't know if there are any drawbacks.

Edit: Erm... *blush*... the 'only default constructor' **is** of course nonsense. Sometimes it pays to think a second or two longer. Especially about constructs, which oneself rarely uses. :-)

Comment: You can use the initializer list to construct member variables a certain way. "There only the default constructor is possible" is wrong.

Comment: In this case it is right since QStackedLayout is not copyable. Try it.

Comment: wrong again. The initialization list of a classes constructor does not have anything to do with copying an object, see http://ideone.com/5TzPXd

Comment: Just try it. 'QStackedLayout layout' in your .h file and 'layout(QStackedLayout(this))' in your initializer list.

Comment: There you are explicitly calling the copy constructor - put `layout(this)` in your list. That works fine. It's logically wrong because of the storage problems, but it compiles fine, and is not using the standard constructor. The only thing you may not do is calling the copy constructor explicitly.

Comment: Bah, stupid me. You are right. I always use pointers in this case. And when not, I do it automatically right, since I don't think about it. Sorryyyy.... :-)